# Wordpress: Background Video on Android and iOS

Tags: wordpress, mobile, responsive-design

I am working on this [website](http://www.lhommecirque-film.ch/) (Developed using Wordpress)  and as you can see i have a **Background Video** in the homepage ( .mp4 file).

The Background Video works on Desktop but not on Android and iOS.

Do you have any tips to solve this issue?

Also via JS...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to convert your video into WEBM and OGV, you could convert it here: 
www.converterpoint.com

Disclaimer: I am the owner of that website

Answer (score 0):

Do you have only one format of background video? .mp4

You need three video files .mp4, .ogg, .webm to make your video play on different browsers and devices:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  <source src="movie.webm" type="video/webm">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```